# Is floating point hardware in modern cpus used for integer operations if not being used for floats?

Tags: floating-point, x86-64

In the event of integer performance intensive application, can the cpu automatically make use of floating point hardware to assist in such calculations? or does the floating point hardware go unused except for floating point specific calculations(e.g. if integer performance limits are being reached, would there be a speed up from changing some of the calculations from integer to floating point calculations in an application's code)?

Comment: considering that int->float can cause corruption of the value, one would hope not... `(int)3 != (int)3.0`, basically

Comment: @MarcB Actually `3.0` represents the value 3 exactly, and floating-point can be used to compute exactly on values that happen to be integers. Did you execute `(int)3 != (int)3.0` in C, Java, C++, …, and did either language  not produce `false` as a result? I would be **extremely** curious about the details.

Comment: well, there's plenty of other values that can't be represented exactly as floats. figures that I'd pick one of the relatively few that can.

Comment: @MarcB All 32 bit integers can be represented exactly in IEEE 754 64-bit binary floating point.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question depends on the processor.

I am sorry to link to a PDF of hundreds of pages, but basically the answer to your question is that you need to read Agner Fog's [optimization manuals](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) to get an insight into how a modern (or even oldish) processor works.

You will note that in some models of processors, some execution ports handle both some floating-point instructions and integer instructions. This makes it vaguely possible that somewhere inside the processor, transistors that could have been used to compute a floating-point operation are being used for an integer operation instead. It is not even necessary (an *execution port* is not the same as an *execution unit*). But even reverse-engineering the workings of modern processors to the scale of the execution port as Agner Fog is doing is a huge undertaking. The question is moot anyway. What matters is how much current the processor consumes and how fast it gets things done. Whether some transistors are shared between integer and floating-point is ony a very small part of this question.

Comment: Integer adders/multipliers need to handle up to 64bit operands.  80-bit float has a 64bit mantissa / significand.  On Intel SnB, FP mul runs on port0, and so does vector int mul.  (Both with 5 cycle latency).  scalar integer mul runs on port 1, though (with 3 cycle latency, same as FP add that's also on that port).  The vector mul unit may or may not share some transistors between FP and int vector mul, but the results come out of different outputs.  There's a data-forwarding bypass delay when using the output of some FP insns as inputs to some vec int insns.